# Calling the APIKit project deployed on Mule 3.8.3 runtime w/o API Gateway

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I created a simple API RAML file with a single GET, no params required, and it returns a simple payload. I pulled that into my project correctly w/ Anypoint Studio (latest as of last week) and created and ran the project locally w/o a hitch. I have a mule runtime on premise 3.8.3 that I have archived and deployed this to successfully. I can see it in the /apps directory w/ the proper .txt file and I see it in the Mule Mgmt Console as a deployed app on my server. I just cannot seem to call it correctly? Can you do that w/ a deployed APIKit project on mule runtime? My simple setup is below and works (of course) w/in the Anypoint studio in Run and Debug mode.

[image]

I call http://localhost:8081/api/testthis as my URL fine but when I go to my mulesoft server where I deployed this and call that IP http://x.x.x.x:8081/api/testthis to just get the payload back it shows no listener. I must be missing a step or a configuration or something, I just cannot seem to search their DOCs or SO site to find the issue.

Any help is appreciated (even if sarcastic!).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:apikit="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http     
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit
 http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit/current/mule-apikit.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">
        <http:listener-config name="testapi-httpListenerConfig" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <apikit:config name="testapi-config" raml="testapi.raml" consoleEnabled="false" doc:name="Router"/>
    <flow name="testapi-main">
        <http:listener config-ref="testapi-httpListenerConfig" path="/api/*" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <apikit:router config-ref="testapi-config" doc:name="APIkit Router"/>
        <exception-strategy ref="testapi-apiKitGlobalExceptionMapping" doc:name="Reference Exception Strategy"/>
    </flow>
    <flow name="testapi-console">
        <http:listener config-ref="testapi-httpListenerConfig" path="/console/*" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <apikit:console config-ref="testapi-config" doc:name="APIkit Console"/>
    </flow>
    <flow name="get:/testthis:testapi-config">
        <set-payload value="[  {&quot;code&quot;: &quot;MyCode1&quot;, &quot;name&quot; : &quot;My Code 1&quot;, &quot;ID&quot; : &quot;1111&quot;  }, {&quot;code&quot;: &quot;MyCode2&quot;, &quot;name&quot; : &quot;My Code 2&quot;, &quot;ID&quot; : &quot;2222&quot;  } ]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    </flow>
    <apikit:mapping-exception-strategy name="testapi-apiKitGlobalExceptionMapping">
        <apikit:mapping statusCode="404">
            <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.apikit.exception.NotFoundException" />
        <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>
        <set-payload value="{ &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Resource not found&quot; }" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    </apikit:mapping>
    <apikit:mapping statusCode="405">
        <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.apikit.exception.MethodNotAllowedException" />
        <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>
        <set-payload value="{ &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Method not allowed&quot; }" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    </apikit:mapping>
    <apikit:mapping statusCode="415">
        <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.apikit.exception.UnsupportedMediaTypeException" />
        <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>
        <set-payload value="{ &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Unsupported media type&quot; }" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    </apikit:mapping>
    <apikit:mapping statusCode="406">
        <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.apikit.exception.NotAcceptableException" />
        <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>
        <set-payload value="{ &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Not acceptable&quot; }" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    </apikit:mapping>
    <apikit:mapping statusCode="400">
        <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.apikit.exception.BadRequestException" />
        <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>
        <set-payload value="{ &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Bad request&quot; }" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    </apikit:mapping>
    </apikit:mapping-exception-strategy>
</mule>
```

Here is where it shows it deployed
[image: zip file deployed under mule apps directory]

And this is how MMC sees it deployed to our 1 dev server.
[image: MMC showing deployed application]

RAML that I used to create the project:

```
#%RAML 0.8
title: mmctest
version: 1.0

/testthis:
  get:
    queryParameters: 
      code:
          displayName: "Code"
          type: string
          description: "The code to pass through on a querystring"
          required: false
    responses: 
      200:
        body: 
          application/json:
            example: |
              [  {"code": "MyCode1", "name" : "My Code 1", "ID" : "1111"  }, {"code": "MyCode2", "name" : "My Code 2", "ID" : "2222"  } ]
```

And my mule-config.xml that it must have to deploy is just a shell file.
[image: mule-config.xml file for deployment]

Comment: Could you pls show your full XML ? Also make sure your `host="0.0.0.0"` instead of localhost

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to put the XML. I edited above to show it. The only thing I am looking to do is have it return the data in the payload. But call it from the mule runtime.

Comment: Well, just to be sure ... what's your RAML file looks like ... I want to compare with the flow generated

Comment: I added the RAML definition, it is fairly basic so as to not have any complexity in this.

Comment: I deployed it in Mule Standalone server and able to get the response with the url `http://localhost:8081/api/testthis` ? where did you deployed ? in local mule standalone server or any other external server ?

Comment: no, it ran localhost:8081/api/testthis in the Anypoint studio with embedded mule runtime. via the Run or Debug w/in the Anypoint Studio. I have yet to successfully call this on the mule runtime after deployment. And the logs show a successful deployment as does the MMC. I am still searching for what I am missing or what step I need to do.  I have a Windows 2012 server box setup with the mule 3.8.3 that is running on its own that I need to deploy this to for integration testing.

Comment: I am not sure why are you facing... I just created the application with the RAML you provided and deployed to my local standalone server via mmc and FYI , it's working fine and I can see the response with the url http://localhost:8081/api/testthis

Comment: Just check with the url http://ipaddress:8081/console/ in browser, are you able to see API console ? ... if not paste your error track trace you are getting in all the cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had 2 things wrong with my setup. So I apologize to Anirban for my taking your time away.

1. I had another app already on 8081 port. So I had to change my port to 8080.
2. I did not archive my project correctly for deployment so I fixed that. Export to Mule > Anypoint Studio Project to Mule Deployable Archive

When I did this correctly, all was fine. So I need to watch for that and make sure I deploy correctly on a valid port not in use.

Comment: Great ... no problem with that .. pls accept your own answer and close the question :)